# MS-Flow / PowerApps - Unresolveable HostName : The provided hostname 'domain.com' cannot be resolved

Tags: azure, flow, powerapp, logic-app

In Flow - I am trying to call a web service using 'http'. It gives me an error message :

> UnResolveableHostName : The Provided host name 'hostname.com' could
>   not be resolved. PostMan/DeveloperDashboard enmurate the results.

Comment: it's behind a firewall.

Comment: @DerekGusoff - what do you mean by behind the firewall.?

Comment: Inside your corporate network and Flow can't reach it.